# calling svnsync with a hook script

Tags: svn, hook, svnsync, subversion-edge

I have a three server subversion edge enviroment running on Windows. I have configured 1 master server and two slave servers using a write through proxy configuration in the apache httpd.conf. I need to configure the replication of the repositories back to the slaves using svnsync but I am stuck on how to modify the hook scripts to accomplish this.  Does anyone have an enviroment simular to mine that would be willing to share what scripts were modified to allow for replication?